# How to print an UITextView iOS 8 objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, uitextview, airprint

I was trying to print through AirPrint one UITextView that the user fills, kind of a note block.
That declaration below is the UITextField I want to print:

```
    IBOutlet UITextView *texto;
```

And this is my printing code:

```
    -(IBAction)imprimir:(id)sender{
UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
print.delegate = self;
NSData* datos=[texto.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
print.printingItem = datos;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName =@"Mis Notas";
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
print.printInfo = printInfo;
print.showsPageRange = YES;
print.printingItem = texto.text;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *,BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print,BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"No se pudo imprimir");
    }
};
[print presentAnimated:NO completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Xcode also says me an error with `print.delegate = self;` as if I need another type of ViewController, I really don´t know.
The sources I found use a normal ViewController.
The error is: "Assigning to 'id<UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate<' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong' ".
Thank you!

Comment: I do not know much about UIPrintInteractionController, but how about interfacing the UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate_Protocol/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController    sharedPrintController];
print.delegate = self;
NSData* datos=[_label.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
print.printingItem = datos;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName =@"Mis Notas";
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
print.printInfo = printInfo;
print.showsPageRange = YES;
print.printingItem = _label.text;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *,BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print,BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"No se pudo imprimir");
    }
};
[print presentAnimated:NO completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but I still have an error... It says: "Assigning to 'id<UIPrinterInteractionControllerDelegate>'from incompatible type 'ViewController *const _strong' ". What could it be... Im sorry im not even an english speaker as well to understand whats the error...

Comment: what's your language?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate>

Comment: yep, iOS 8.4 and my language is Spanish